# How we can use unix-socket with python3 urllib or with requests

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, urllib3

How I can use the following in python3 with urllib or with requests

```
curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http://localhost/images/json
```

If this is possible then somebody help me?

Comment: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.connection.html

Comment: It would be great if there is any real code example

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.

Obviously, the main advantage is that it does not require any dependency.

It sent an `HTTP request` to the UNIX socket opened by Docker to retrieve the container list via JSON.

```
async def get_containers():
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_unix_connection("/var/run/docker.sock")
    query = (
        f"GET /containers/json HTTP/1.0\r\n"
        f"\r\n"
    )
    writer.write(query.encode('utf-8'))
    await writer.drain()
    writer.write_eof()
    headers = True
    while headers:
        line = await reader.readline()
        if line == b"\r\n":
            headers = False
        elif not line:
            break
    containers = []
    if not headers:
        data = await reader.readline()
        containers = json.loads(data.decode("utf-8"))
    writer.close()
    await writer.wait_closed()
    return containers

c = asyncio.run(get_containers())
```